# Error compiling with RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift

I'm trying to add RxSwift to my project. Added RxSwift and RxCocoa to my Podfile but when I compile I get this error:

[image: error]

Tried in another empty project and it all works fine. Can't find what's causing this.

EDIT:

Seems like it fails to build Rx-Cocoa. No idea why.

[image: error]

Comment: remember to import RxCocoa

Comment: I actually didn't import anything. Just compiling.

Comment: i guess you, have imported rxswift, right?

Comment: Nope! didn't import anything. Only pod install'd

Comment: It should be `self.base.text` instead of `self.text`

Comment: If changed to self.base.text there's a new error: `...TextInput.swift:37:58: Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'ControlProperty<String?>' (aka 'ControlProperty<Optional<String>>')`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `self.text`, That's wrong you can access the `Base` class you are extending through `base` property.

In this case `base` property is gonna be `UITextField`.

```
extension Reactive where Base: UITextField {

    public var textInput: TextInput<Base> {
        return TextInput(base: base, text: base.text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

//code insert here!!
```

Comment: Haven't didn't imported anything. Only pod install'd